# sed (v4.2.1) or awk to solve a regex substition

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

https://regex101.com/r/t1Etzx/1/ is doing the regex substitution ok.
using sed 4.2.1 on bash:

```
echo "text curl -u a12345:ypB7HuW9u5yB'_'https://mycompany.com/api/healthcheck"|sed -r 's/(a\d+|A\d+|scl[^:]+):([^\']+)(\'|_)/\1:xxxxx\3/g'
```

and

```
echo "text curl -u a12345:ypB7HuW9u5yB'_'https://mycompany.com/api/healthcheck"|sed -E 's/(a\d+|A\d+|scl[^:]+):([^\']+)(\'|_)/\1:xxxxx\3/g'
```

are giving me

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

A solution in awk welcome too.

Comment: `sed` does not support `\d`. Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `\d` doesn't work, so i replaced it with `[0-9]`.
Also replaced `(\'|_)` with `[\'_]`, because that didn't work either.
As for the `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ')'`, replace single quotes with double quotes, because `'\''` doesn't work, because `\` in single quotes is literal.
So that seems to work:

```
sed -E "s/(a[0-9]+|A[0-9]+|scl[^:]+):([^\'_]+)([\'_])/\1:xxxxx\3/g"
```

Comment: You should not answer such evident duplicates. It is common knowledge POSIX regex does not support `\d`. Just flag these questions as duplicates.